# Function with domain all real numbers and range $(0,1)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Is there a *one-to-one* function whose domain is all real numbers and range is $(0,1)$?

I can't find any so I was thinking about trying to find a piece-wise function that meets the requirements, but I'm having a lot of trouble doing that too.

This is a part of the problem I'm trying to solve to show that two sets have the same cardinality.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Fiddle around with $\arctan$.

Comment: Any CDF of a suitable random variable does the job, for instance $$ g(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{t} e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

The logistic function satisfies those requirements:

$$ f(x) = \frac{\exp(x)}{1+\exp(x)} $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

find $a,b$ in $y=a \arctan (x) +b$ so the your condition is satisfied.

Comment: I was thinking (arctan(x) / pi ) + 0.5. I'm assuming this works because the limit as arctan(x) goes to infinity is pi/2, but dividing by pi makes that 1/2 and adding 1/2 makes that 1.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(0,1)\to (-1, 1)$ by $f(0,1) \to (-1,1):f(x) = 2x - 1$.

Now stretch $-1\mapsto -\infty$, $0\mapsto 0$, $1\mapsto \infty$ by .... how? Well as $x\to 0$ we have $\frac 1x \to \infty$ so $x\to 1^-$ we have $\frac 1{x-1}\to \infty$. But $\frac 1{x-1}$ will map $0\to 1$.  But we can do $g[0,1)\to [0,\infty):g(x) =\frac 1{x-1}-1$.

And we do the same for the negative values $h:(-1, 0]\mapsto (-\infty, 0]: h(x)=\frac 1{x+1}+1$.

So we have $G: (0,1)\to \mathbb R$ via $G(x)=\begin{cases}\frac 1{(2x-1)-1}-1&x\ge \frac 12\\\frac 1{(2x-1)+1}&x < \frac 12\end{cases}=\begin{cases}\frac 1{2x-2}-1&x\ge \frac 12\\\frac 1{2x}+1&x < \frac 12\end{cases}$

And so $G^{-1}\mathbb R\to (0,1)$ can be $\begin{cases} \frac 1{2(y+1)} + 1&x \ge 0\\\frac 1{2(y+1)}&x < 0\end{cases}$ will do it.

....

But there are better functions.

You shouldn't think to hard about these.  You should realize the *must* be possible so then just draw pictures and figure it out.

A *better* function is to note $\tan: (-\frac {\pi}2, \frac {\pi}2) \to \mathbb R$.

So $\arctan: \mathbb R \to (-\frac {\pi}2,\frac {\pi}2)$.

And $\frac 2{\pi}\arctan x: \mathbb R \to (-1, 1)$.

And $\frac {\frac 2{\pi}\arctan x + 2}2: \mathbb R \to (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n \in \mathbb N$ (including $0$) let $f_n \colon [n, n+1] \to \mathbb R$ be unique polynomial of degree $1$ such that $f_n(n) = 1- \frac{1}{n}$ and $f_n(n+1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$. $(\dagger)$

Then $f := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} f_n \colon [0, \infty) \to [0,1)$ is injective.

Figure out how to extend $f$ on $(- \infty, 0]$ to an injective function $g \colon \mathbb R \to (-1,1)$ and then consider the injective function
$$
h \colon \mathbb R \to (0,1), x \mapsto \frac{g(x) +1}{2}.
$$

---

$(\dagger)$ $f_n$ is essentially a line segment with smaller and smaller inclination as $n$ tends towards $\infty$.